# Python Operator |= meaning

Tags: python

due to some versioning problems with python I am bound to use a custom function to compare HMACs (SHA512). To do so I have found this function:

```
def compare_digest(x, y):
    if not (isinstance(x, bytes) and isinstance(y, bytes)):
        logfile.debug("both inputs should be instances of bytes")
    if len(x) != len(y):
        return False
    result = 0
    for a, b in zip(x, y):
        result |= a ^ b
    return result == 0
```

I am using this in Django, hence I created a logger (logfile) that saves debug messages into a file for me.

The code breaks at this step:

```
result |= a ^ b
```

However, I have no idea what the |= operator stands for and what happens here. If someone could explain this I could try to rewrite this.

My python version is (unfortunately 2.7.4) with 2.7.7 I would not have the problem, as the function would have been ported correctly and made available.

Comment: `result |= a ^ b` boils down to `result = result | (a ^ b)`. The value of `result` will be nonzero if exactly one of `a` and `b` is `1`.

Comment: BTW why don't you just compare objects as in `x == y`? If you must scan the objects, why don't you use easier to understand logic like `if a != b: return False`?

Comment: As far as I have understood this, the problem relies in a timing attack in which an attacker gets an advantage. But I did not read into the full details.

Comment: If a timing attack is an issue (it might be), I think the rest of conditiona operators must be eliminated. Something like `reduce(lambda acc, (m, n): acc and (m == n), zip(a, b), True)` will always execute in _O(len(a))_ time and return `True` iff `a == b` element-wise. You could consider padding both `x` and `y` to the same length to avoid timing attack that finds out the length, but SHA512 digests are expected to be the same length anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. `|=` is the bitwise OR equivalent of `+=`, `-=`, etc. Basically, `a |= b` is shorthand for `a = a | b`.

Comment: Ok, that seems kind of obvious [feeling stupid]. But I still don't understand why this would break.

Comment: Open a new question for that imho; it's considered good practice to limit SO posts to a single question with an answer, to the extent that's possible. And when you do, give the error message/stack trace ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bit wise **or and assignment** in one step. Kind of like

```
a+=1 # which means a = a + 1
```